# Is it necessary to explicitly clear databindings before control disposal?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I just read an old blog article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996446.aspx#databinding_winforms10_11_topic11) that advises calling `.databindings.Clear()` before disposing to avoid memory leaks. The article was written with .Net 1.0/1.1 in mind, is this still necessary or advisable in .Net > 1.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dedicated method for that is Control.ResetBindings().  And no, you don't have to call it yourself, it is automatically called by the Control.Dispose() method.  You can see this for yourself from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,d85b7dd334cd518d) code, net/fx/src/Winforms/Managed/System/Winforms/Control.cs source code file.